# C code compiles but in arduino sketch it doesn't

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-c++

I have some C code which compiles with GNU GCC but when i put it on an arduino sketch it says

> cannot convert 'const float' to 'float (*)[25]' for argument '1' to
>   'float dot_product(float (*)[25], float*)'

In the sketch there is function sigmoid and forward and dot_p which are all defined, I am trying to store some values on the sketch itself, because i cannot store all the values on the EEPROM, please any extra clarification i can provide if you can help

the sketch is as follows:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
const int rs = 12, en = 11, d4 = 5, d5 = 4, d6 = 3, d7 = 2;
LiquidCrystal lcd(rs, en, d4, d5, d6, d7);

const float a[25][25] = { A LONG LIST OF NUMBERS arranged in 25X25};

  float b[25]={Another list of numbers};
 void setup() {}

 void loop() {}

 float dot_product(float v[][25], float u[])
{

    for (int j = 0; j< 25; j++){
             float result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++){
        result += u[i]*v[j][i];

    }
    return result;
    }
}
double forward(float x){

    float lm[25];
    double km[25];
    double t=0;
    double output=0;
    for(int i=0; i <25; i++){
        lm[i] = 0;
        km[i] = 0;
    }
    for (int k=0; k<25; k++){
        lm[k]= dot_product(a[k],x);
        /*** THIS IS THE ERROR SOURCE***/


    }

     for (int j=0; j<25;j++){
      km[j] = sigmoid(lm[j]);

    }


    t = dot_p(km,b);
    output = sigmoid(t);

    return output;

}
```

Comment: C or C++ code?`

Comment: @Antti neither? Currently it is turning a float into a pointer (An array parameter is a pointer.) GCC should not accept this code without massive warnings. And even if GCC compiles it, it cannot work. A dot product function typically takes 2 vectors at parameter, but it is defined to take a matrix and a vector, and you feed it a vector and a scalar. It is impossible to fix this code without knowing what it is supposed to do. At the moment it is to messy to make a sane guess.

Comment: It is easier to get this to compile as C++ however given the constructor call there....

Comment: Getting it to compile is easy. Getting it to do what it is supposed to do is hard without more info. Especially guessing what the purpose of `forward` is, is problematic.

Answer (score 0):

after removing all the 'unneeded' code and correcting several small errors, the result is:

```
// if you really want 'const', 
// then all references must also be 'const'
float a[25][25];

// the second parameter is from a float value
// not from an array of float values
float dot_product( float v[][25], float u )
{
    // initialize the float variable from a float literal
    // rather than from a double literal
    float result = 0.0f;

    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        // since the function exits after summing a single
        // row, the 'j' is replaced with 0
        result += u * v[0][i];
    }
    return result;
}


void forward(float x)
{
    float lm = 0.0f;

    for (int k=0; k<25; k++)
    {
        // note: passing address of 'a[k]'
        lm += dot_product( &a[k], x );
    }
}
```

Comment: A function called `dot_product` should typically calculate the dot product of two vectors. Just hacking on the posters code until it compiles, with no regard of what the code is supposed to do isn't typically very helpful. But then, this answer just shows how messy the original code was